# Get value of editable <td> tag through oninput function?

Tags: javascript

```
<td contenteditable="true" class="name_of_child" oninput="set_text(this,'name_of_child_1')"></td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="date_of_birth" oninput="set_text(this,'date_of_birth_1')"></td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="living_or_deceased" oninput="set_text(this,'living_or_deceased_1')"></td>
```

I want to get the text through `oninput` function from table `td` element like this, but sadly this works with input fields but not with table `td` tags. Is there a way to get the `td` text using `oninput` or any other way?

Comment: So what is set_text? My guess you are reading value and there is no value with a td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the innerHTML or textContent of the reference you pass in to get what the user typed.

```js
function set_text(td, foo) {
   console.log(td.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
table, tr { width: 100%;}
td { width: 33%;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" class="name_of_child" oninput="set_text(this,'name_of_child_1')">x</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" class="date_of_birth" oninput="set_text(this,'date_of_birth_1')">y</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" class="living_or_deceased" oninput="set_text(this,'living_or_deceased_1')">z</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think this method will work for me , thanks for the help . I got an idea of how to get the value .

Answer (score 1):

You can give unique id to each `td` and then try to access the value by passing id into `oninput` function.

```
<td id="td1" contenteditable="true" class="name_of_child"oninput="set_text(this,'td1')"></td>
<td id="td2" contenteditable="true" class="date_of_birth" oninput="set_text(this,'td2')"></td>
<td id="td3" contenteditable="true" class="living_or_deceased" oninput="set_text(this,'td3')"></td>
```

`set_text` function:

```
function set_text(this, id) {
    var val = document.getElementById(id).textContent
}
```

Comment: There is zero need to pass in the id. What do you think `this` is?

Answer (score 1):

Why not go more abstract?

```js
const data = {}

const setup = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(td => td.addEventListener('input', setText));
  
  const btn = document.querySelector('button');
  btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => console.log(data));
}

const updateObject = (key, value) => data[key] = value;

const setText = (event) => {
    const target = event.currentTarget;
  const key = target.dataset.var;
  const value = target.textContent;
  
  updateObject(key, value);
}

window.addEventListener('load', setup)
```

```css
td {
  background: red;
  min-width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" data-var="name_of_child"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" data-var="date_of_birth"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" data-var="living_or_deceased"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>
Show Object
</button>
```